# able to kill ngrok tunnely remotely in terminal on other pc?

Tags: localhost, ngrok

1. Not too sure if this question belongs in StackOverflow if it doesn't please me know where I should move to.
2. A question of being lazy.

I registered for ngrok as a free plan user.
Free plan limited to 1 simultaneous ngrok client session, I do use it while I am using my desktop but let's say if I forgot to close it after I am done and next day I woke up in my bed using my laptop being lazy to go to where the desktop is.  I am then not able to turn on ngrok on my laptop because desktop is running it.

Is there a way to close ngrok remotely?  I thought maybe I could kill from ngrok's dashboard but doesn't seem there's such option though.

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can do is regenerate your authtoken from the ngrok dashboard. That will disconnect any current agents so you can start a new one.